# Ensuring the atomicity of multiple transactions

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain

I am new to solidity and have been creating single (both basic and complex) transactions. However, I have a question which I couldn't come up with a solution.

How can I create 2 (or more) transactions but the whole structure must be atomic such that either all of the transactions are processed or none of them. How can I achieve such a process?

I am not looking for direct answers as I love to try and do new things, however, I couldn't come up with a solution for this one.

My initial idea was the following:

**Creating a smart contract to receive transactions -> pack them together (how?) -> send them all at once**

A question about this structure is, should we check the validity of the contract before packing them and abort the process? Or after the packing, somehow?